# Amazon MWS: Amazon SQS does not get MWS messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-mws

Im working with Amazon MWS, and I need to get a notification (SQS message) if [FulfillmentOrderStatusNotification](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_FulfillmentOrderStatusNotification.html), is set, which notifies you if there is a multi channel order status change.

In the documentation of MWS (https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_Overview.html), there is:

> The Amazon MWS push notifications enable you to receive information
>   that is relevant to your business with Amazon without having to poll
>   the Amazon MWS service. Instead, the information is sent directly to
>   you when an event occurs to which you are subscribed. For more
>   information about how to subscribe to receive notifications, see
>   Subscriptions Overview in the Amazon MWS Subscriptions API section
>   reference.

Then, in the 'Subscriptions API' section:

> The Amazon MWS Subscriptions API section enables you to subscribe to
>   receive notifications that are relevant to your business with Amazon.
>   With the operations in the Subscriptions API section, you can register
>   to receive important information from Amazon without having to poll
>   the Amazon MWS service. Instead, the information is sent directly to
>   you when an event occurs to which you are subscribed.
>
> To receive notifications, you must first create and register a
>   Destination, such as an Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS)
>   queue. Then, you create a Subscription for the NotificationType that
>   you want to receive, such as a notification when another Seller has
>   changed their offer for an item that you also sell. Finally, verify
>   that Amazon is able to send notifications to your Destination by
>   calling the SendTestNotificationToDestination operation.

I did all of it, I have created a new SQS, with all permissions, and I have created (from amazon [scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html)) a subscription with the SQS as a destination, also, once Im getting the list of the subscriptions, I can see them all, but, somehow, I didn't received any subscription message in the last few days (Many orders status has changed), I have tried to send a test SQS message, and I could see it successfully.

anyone tried to work with it? any idea what am I missing here?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and wondered whether you are able to solve this mystery.

Comment: unfortunately, I couldn't, so I'm calling amazon every X minutes... Ill love to hear if you could

Comment: About 3 years later, we faced the exactly same problem. :)